# bidirectional resultset in spring jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-jdbc

We are using NamedParmaeterJdbcTemplate in our spring jdbc code. By default it is returning forward only resultset. Can we configure anywhere (without overriding NamedParameterJdbcTemplate) the type of result set in spring jdbc.

We are using the following method.

```
query(String sql, SqlParameterSource paramSource, ResultSetExtractor<T> rse)
    throws DataAccessException
```

Comment: did you check setting `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE` ?

Comment: Where can I configure spring to use TYPE_SCROLL_INSESNITIVE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` isn't flexible enough to do that, since it uses a hard-wired `PreparedStatementCreatorFactory` object to create the statement. You need to be able to call `PreparedStatementCreatorFactory #setResultSetType` to get a scrollable resultset.

Subclassing `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` and overriding the `getPreparedStatementCreator` method to create a correctly configured `PreparedStatementCreatorFactory` is the only way to do what you want to do.